# Couldn't find a `pages` directory. Please create one under the project root

Tags: reactjs, next.js

Having some trouble when running npm run dev

I get the following error:

> Error: > Couldn't find a `pages` directory. Please create one under the project root

Here is an image of the 'pages' I put in.

[image: Here is an image of the pages I put in]

Any ideas?

Here is the package.json:

```
{
    "name": "adonis-fullstack-app",
    "version": "4.1.0",
    "adonis-version": "4.1.0",
    "description": "The fullstack application boilerplate for Adonisjs",
    "main": "index.js",
    "scripts": {
        "start": "NODE_ENV=production node server.js",
        "dev": " NODE_ENV=development adonis serve --dev --ignore=\"./storage/framework/next\" ",
        "build": "next build ./storage/framework/next",
        "begin": "npm install && cp .env.example .env",
        "stories": "start-storybook -p 9001 -c ./storage/framework/storybook",
        "lint-staged": "lint-staged"
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you share your `package.json` sample?

Comment: you pages directory should be the root level - meaning same level as your package.json file. otherwise you you can change the baseUrl configuration the match your needs

Answer (score 0):

I know you made this post a long time ago, so the chances are it has probably already been solved.

But as I ran into the same issue, I managed to find a solution that worked for me, so I just thought I would leave it here in case it can be of any help to anyone else in the future.

Similarly to the OP, I have my directory set up as:

```
¬ project-root-dir
  ¬ frontend-dir
    ¬ website-dir
```

By doing it this way allows me to create additional projects in the same root directory folder (**for example:** if I wanted to create a backend for an admin panel, I could create a completely separate application in a **backend\admin** directory).

An example of how the updated project structure might look:

```
¬ project-root-dir
  ¬ frontend-dir
    ¬ website-dir
  ¬ backend-dir
    ¬ admin-panel-dir
```

By doing this, we can now have a **package.json** file in each of the directories, (**e.g - website & admin-panel**) and this is the trick into getting the **Next.JS** to recognise the **/pages/** directory.

So make sure that your **package.json** file sits inside of the project that you want to install the packages.
In my example, I had initially created it in the **root-project-dir** but in fact, needed to be in the **frontend\website** directory

Updated project structure:

```
¬ project-root-dir
  ¬ frontend-dir
    ¬ website-dir
      ¬ pages
        ¬ index.js
      ¬ package.json
  ¬ backend-dir
    ¬ admin-panel-dir
```

I was then able to run **npm install** in the **frontend\website** directory to install the packages, so they no longer resided in the **root project directory**, then, when running **npm run dev** it succeeded with finding the **/pages/** directory and I am able to browse the site as I continue development.