# Couldn't find a `pages` directory. Please create one under the project root Firebase deploy to Hosting

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

I'm using Firebase Hosting to deploy my web app which uses NextJS.  In the last deploy in late March 2023 I was able to deploy with the following steps but now I get an error where the `pages` directory is not found even though I am running the deploy command at the root of the project where `pages` is.

```bash
firebase deploy --only hosting
```

But running the Firebase command, the process is successful in initiating other Firebase services.

```
+  functions: .firebase\myprojectprod\functions folder uploaded successfully
i  hosting[myprojectprod]: beginning deploy...
i  hosting[myprojectprod]: found 109 files in .firebase\myprojectprod\hosting
+  hosting[myprojectprod]: file upload complete
i  functions: updating Node.js 16 function firebase-frameworks-myprojectprod:ssrmyprojectprod(us-central1)...
Build failed with status: FAILURE and message: > myprojectprod@0.3.0 build 
> next build 
... 
> Build error occurred
Error: > Couldn't find a `pages` directory. Please create one under the project root
    at Object.findPagesDir (/workspace/node_modules/next/dist/lib/find-pages-dir.js:86:19)
    at /workspace/node_modules/next/dist/build/index.js:103:63
    at async Span.traceAsyncFn (/workspace/node_modules/next/dist/trace/trace.js:79:20)
    at async Object.build [as default] (/workspace/node_modules/next/dist/build/index.js:66:29). For more details see the logs at https://console.cloud.google.com/cloud-build/builds;region=us-central1/xxx?project=xxx.

Functions deploy had errors with the following functions:
        firebase-frameworks-myprojectprod:ssrmyprojectprod(us-central1)
i  functions: cleaning up build files...
```

Issue seems to be with Cloud Functions.  I deleted the function created by the deploy command and a new one is created.

firebase.json

```json
{
  "hosting": {
    "source": ".",
    "ignore": ["firebase.json", "**/.*", "**/node_modules/**"],
    "frameworksBackend": {
      "region": "us-central1"
    }
  },
  "firestore": {
    "rules": "firestore.rules"
  }
}
```

next.config.js

```json
module.exports = withBundleAnalyzer({
  transpilePackages: ["@stripe/firestore-stripe-payments"],
  i18n: {
    locales: ["en"],
    defaultLocale: "en"
  },
  images: {
    remotePatterns: [
      {
        protocol: "https",
        hostname: "storage.googleapis.com",
        pathname: `/my-bucket`,
      },
    ],
  },
  devIndicators: {
    buildActivity: false,
  },
})
```

Project directory

```
pages/
    blogs/
        [blogId].tsx
        blog-index.tsx  
    index.js 
    catalog.tsx 
    login.tsx 
    account.tsx 
    404.js 
    500.js
public/ 
    favicon.ico 
    images/ 
        icon1.png 
themes/

firebase.json 
package.json 
tsconfig.json 
firestore.rules 
firebase.ts 
.env.production 
.env.local 
css/ 
components/ 
    ... 
firebase_utils/ 
    ...
```

I've tried

- [Couldn't find a `pages` directory. Please create one under the project root](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61315899/couldnt-find-a-pages-directory-please-create-one-under-the-project-root)
- Clean deploy: git clone, npm install, firebase init, firebase deploy --only hosting
- Running `firebase experiments:enable webframeworks` before deploy command
- Deleting the Cloud Functions function which generates on deploy
- Using the `"public": "public"` option in the `firebase.json` since the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/full-config#specify-files-to-deply) says it's required (I don't think it is)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay it works now.  What worked is the combination of deleting the function in Cloud Functions and updating Firebase tools with `npm install -g firebase-tools`

Comment: Thanks, updating and deleting the function worked for me too.

Answer (score 2):

Went into the firebase console, then the functions window (under the build dropdown) and deleted the older function.
then did `firebase deploy`
that solved it

Answer (score 0):

Actually all this time, you already have the clue!

Both of us are using: firebase experiments:enable webframeworks

The only solution to this:

- export your nextjs
- set your firebase.json

> public: hosting/out

where:

- hosting => nextjs folder
- out => automatically created by export

Hope this works.